# wso2 message broker topic list

Tags: wso2, broker

I m working on WSO2 Message Broker 2.0.0.

I have to write a **Java Code to get list of all the TOPICS** created/available in message broker.

Is there an API to do this?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No What i have explored till now. You can't get the topic names from message broker 2.0. I dont know about upcoming Version but till that version, I din't find any thing to get topic list created in Message broker.